# Extract year, month and day from matrix column in one line of code

Tags: r, matrix, format, as.date

I'd like to shorten my code.

My current approach is:

```
year = as.numeric(format(as.Date(matrix[,dt_ind]), format = "%Y"))
month = as.numeric(format(as.Date(matrix[,dt_ind]), format="%m"))
day = as.numeric(format(as.Date(matrix[,dt_ind]), format="%d"))
```

and my data looks like this:

```
dput(matrix[1:10,dt_ind]) = c("2018-01-01_0000", "2018-01-01_0000", "2018-01-01_0000", "2018-01-01_0000", 
"2018-01-01_0000", "2018-01-01_0000", "2018-01-01_0000", "2018-01-01_0000", 
"2018-01-01_0000", "2018-01-01_0000")
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Generally, in R, you have to define 1 object at a time. So if you need 3 objects defined with different values and different names, you need 3 lines to do it. I would actually recommend simplifying your code by adding 1 more line, start with `date = as.Date(matrix[,dt_ind])` so that you don't have to repeat that piece of code 3 times. You can then do `year = as.numeric(format(date, format = "%Y"))`, etc.

Comment: Or you can use `library(lubridate)` and do `year = year(date)` and `month = month(date)`, etc.

Comment: You could make a matrix of year, month, day values with `apply(stringr::str_split(matrix[,dt_ind], pattern = "[-_]", simplify=TRUE)[,1:3], 2, as.numeric)`, but I'm not sure this is better.  It's probably fewer keystrokes, but less transparent and readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We refer to the vector shown in the question as `v` and define it reproducibly in the Note at the end.

**1)** This gives a data frame whose columns are the required vectors. No packages are used.

```
read.table(text = v, sep = "-", comment.char = "_", 
  col.names = c("year", "month", "day"))

##    year month day
## 1  2018     1   1
## 2  2018     1   1
...snip...
```

If you really do want separate vectors in th e global environment or replalce `.GlobalEnv` with `environment()` if you want them in the current environment.  (These two will be the same if the current environment is the global environment.)

```
list2env(read.table(text = v, sep = "-", comment.char = "_", 
  col.names = c("year", "month", "day")), .GlobalEnv)
```

**2)** The chron package has a function which does this.

```
library(chron)

month.day.year(v)
## $month
##  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
##
## $day
##  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
##
## $year
##  [1] 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018
```

or this.  The point about `enviornment()` applies here too.

```
list2env(month.day.year(v), .GlobalEnv)
```

### Note

The input reproducibly:

```
v <- rep("2018-01-01_0000", 10L)
```